# How can I change the switch display based on the value from the database

Tags: php, jquery, css

So I have a switch for each day of the week, simple html and css. When the switch is clicked to on/off position it sends the event to jquery which then sends it to PHP to update the database. Then I am querying that database to get the value for each day (1 for ON, 0 for OFF).

How can I change the display of the switch based on a 1 or 0 value from PHP. For example: if the value from the database is 1, then the ::after css should be displayed(green). if it is a 0 then the ::before should be displayed(grey). And of course the user can simply change it by clicking on the switch.

Here is the code for the switch:

```
if($row['monday'] == '1'){ 
    echo'<div class="material-switch" style="margin-left:45%;">
       <input id="mondaySelect" name="mondaySelect" type="checkbox"/>
       <label for="mondaySelect" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>';                    
}
```

Here is the CSS for the switch, the switch when selected changes to on position and green color, when clicked again goes grey to the off position.

```
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;   
}

.material-switch > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative; 
    width: 40px;  
}

.material-switch > label::before {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 8px;
    content: '';
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    width: 40px;
}
.material-switch > label::after {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    content: '';
    height: 24px;
    left: -4px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 24px;
}
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background: inherit;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    background: inherit;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Here is a picture for clarity

[image]

Comment: How does it currently work when a switch is turned ON or OFF? How do you assign the appropriate class?

Comment: @ NawedKhan The switch just turns on and off with css, all of the code here is the code for the switch to turn on or off...Its just a checkbox, and I use jquery to check if the checkbox is checked or not, then send that value to php. All of that works fine, just need to know how to change the CSS once I get the value from the database. So when the checkbox comes back unchecked, is there a way to change the CSS for the box to the ::before or ::after code.

Comment: Then just put checked in the input if the corresponding value is 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: @NawedKhan, yeah that worked. Haha, that totally had slipped my mind. Thinking too much about the ::before and ::after in the css.  :)   thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `CSS` depends on the `checked` attribute of the checkbox. If it's checked it will display the switch as on, otherwise it will display the switch as off which is a good `CSS` design.

We can make use of that simply in PHP, by just echo the `"checked"` attribute if the value from Database is 1, otherwise don't echo "checked".

For example Change this

```
if($row['monday'] == '1'){ 
    echo'<div class="material-switch" style="margin-left:45%;">
       <input id="mondaySelect" name="mondaySelect" type="checkbox"/>
       <label for="mondaySelect" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>';                    
}
```

To this

```
if($row['monday'] == '1')$mondayChecked = "checked";
else $mondayChecked = "";

echo'<div class="material-switch" style="margin-left:45%;">
   <input id="mondaySelect" name="mondaySelect" type="checkbox" ' 
   . $mondayChecked .' />
   <label for="mondaySelect" class="label-success"></label>
</div>';
```

Comment: as simple as that. Thanks for the help, that definitely worked. Appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome, yes it's very simple because it's CSS is good.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use material switch, it may be worth to implement https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/switches/

You can attach the code into your template and check if it works.

```
<!-- Required styles for MDC Web -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">

if($row['monday'] == '1'){ 
    echo'<div class="mdc-switch mdc-switch--checked">
  <div class="mdc-switch__track"></div>
  <div class="mdc-switch__thumb-underlay">
    <div class="mdc-switch__thumb">
      <input type="checkbox" id="basic-switch" class="mdc-switch__native-control" role="switch" checked>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';                    
}
```

Comment: I checked it out but I think that Accountants solution was very simple and created the result I was looking for. Thanks